# Is there a field where the set is R and 1+1=11?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am referring to a way in which we can redefine the additive and multiplicative operations and still have a field. So far I was only able to obtain a group by defining the operation ‘w’ such as XwY=X+Y+9 in which -9 is the neutral element.I have trouble finding an adequate multiplicative operation.

Comment: $XtY=(X+9)(Y+9)-9$ and $XsY=(X+9)+(Y+9)-9=X+Y+9$ gives you a field with $-9$ the additive identity and $-8$ the multiplicative identity. It's a boring field, in the it is isomorphic to whatever your original field was.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't demand that the new field structure have some connection to the old one, then practically anything can happen.

For example, let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=x$ for $x\not\in\{11, 2\}$ and $f(11)=2, f(2)=11$.

Then we can "push" the usual field structure through $f$: let $$a+_{new}b=f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b)), \quad a\times_{new}b=f^{-1}(f(a)\times f(b)).$$ It's not hard to check that this gives a field structure on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying $1+_{new}1=11$.

Comment: No reason to use $f^{-1}$ since $f^{-1}=f$. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but I wanted to write it this way to make it clear how the pushthrough works for general bijections.